# How can i Fetch USB Device Bus-Type GUID properties through node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, usb, usb-descriptor

I am trying to check if USB Debugging is turned on or off through NPM/Node. As soon as an android phone is connected to my system and USB Debugging is turned off, then i need to show a prompt to user to enable usb debugging on his phone.

According to my research, every device (Scanner/Phones/USB) connected to my system has a unique GUID which helps me to distinguish which device is connected. Further, i'm not able to fetch the usb debugging details. 
Please help!

[I want this property which is in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al97x.png)

Code which i have written so far is on the basis of **iSerialNumber** but i want to distinguish it on the basis of **BUS-TYPE GUID**.

```
var usb = require('usb');

usb.on('attach', function(device) 
{
    var devices = usb.getDeviceList();
    var check = devices[0].deviceDescriptor;
    if(check.iSerialNumber == '3')
    {
        console.log("Please enable USB Debugging");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Connect an Android device");
    }
});
```

**Here is the latest code which i have tried, but it works only for Samsung devices:-**

```
var usbDetect = require('usb-detection');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var adb = require('adbkit');
var client = adb.createClient();

usbDetect.on('add', function(dev) {
    setTimeout(checkAndyDevice, 1500);
 }); 

var checkAndyDevice = function(){
 client.listDevices()
      .then(function(devices) {
        return Promise.map(devices, function() {
          return devices;
        })
      })
      .then(function(id) {
        if((JSON.stringify(id)) == '[]')
        {
            console.log("Please enable Usb Debugging option from your Android device");
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error('Something went wrong:', err.stack)
      });
 };
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please show us what you have tried so far... Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for details

Comment: @StephenReindl here is the code which i have achieved so far.